# Access to fetch at port: 8000 from origin Port :3000 has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django-rest-framework, react-redux, cors, redux-toolkit, next.js13

I am trying to access my back-end api form Next Js 13(APP Route). it is giving me this error.
I am using redux rdk query to post the data.

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/user/create/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

my code:

On form submit.

```
const onSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();


    register({ name, mobile, email, password, password2 })
        .unwrap()
        .then(() => {
            toast.success('Please check email to verify account');
            router.push('/auth/login');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            toast.error('Failed to register account');
        });
};
```

// API slice.

```
    register: builder.mutation({
        query: ({
            name,
            mobile,
            email,
            password,
            password2,
        }) => ({
            url: '/create/',
            method: 'POST',
            body: { name, mobile, email, password, password2 },
        }),
    }),
```

Please help

my back-end is on http://127.0.0.1:8000 and i am using Django for back-end
my front end is on 3000 port and using Next Js 13(App Route)
Please help with possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to make a whitelist FrontEnd URL

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', # <-------- this
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <-------- this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'sales_company_app.get_user_instance.RequestMiddleware',
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # <-------- this
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",    # React (FrontEnd Url) # <-------- this
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*' # <-------- this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] # (Api Base Url) <-------- this (allow csrf_token) for doing whitelist
```